# Flutter - Syntax in Android Manifest for AdMob support

Tags: android, flutter, admob, android-manifest

I have seen that now, to use AdMob into android app, it is mandatory to include the following lines into the `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<meta-data
     android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
     android:value="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxxxxxx" />
```

My question is : am I suppose to replace "APPLICATION_ID" with my application id (package name) or just leave it like this ?

I have tried both possibilities, but I always receive `Ad failed to load : 3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's like a key and value, so it will be liked that

```
<meta-data
 android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
 android:value="YOUR_APP_ID_HERE" />
```

Change the value of `YOUR_APP_ID_HERE` to your application id, it will be something like that `ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxxxxxx`

Where you can find it? From AdMob website after making an account, you will be able to create new application, after the creation, you will get the app id, copy and paste it.

Hope my answer helps you.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I had 2 problems. I had not realized that ```com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID``` was an ID so I had replaced it with ```com.google.android.gms.ads.my.package.name```. But the most important problem was that I had put the ```meta-data``` tag under the ```activity``` tag and not directly under the ```application``` tag.

Comment: Hi I would like to ask, as I know that we can't place ca-app-pub id on the same widget tree (for axample: placing ca-app-pub id in first screen and second screen). So I just need to make sure that I am doing the correct thing, to show ads in first screen and the second one we need to define diffent ca-app-pub id by defining multiple ca-app-pub in android manifest. am I right if I say something like that ?